# R: google translate API (packages 'translate' & ''translateR')

Tags: r, google-translate, translate

I am trying to use the `translate` and `translateR` packages with R-Studio.

I have created both a 'server' and 'browser' API key. The browser API works fine when running the example:

https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=YOUR_API_KEY&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de

However, when using either API key and either package with R-Studio (`translate`/`translateR`), I obtain an error message. With `translate`

```
> library(translate)
> set.key("mykey")
> translate('Hello, world!', 'en', 'de')
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

What might be the issue? Thanks for help!

Comment: Server and browser API's won't help you, you need Google's translate API. https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify? I have already enabled Google's translate API - that is how I got the 'server' and 'browser' API keys originally. The R packages `translate` and `translateR` should to my understanding work with these keys. What am I missing?

Comment: Did your API request require having a google account with billing information on file? If not, then you got the wrong API.

Comment: Yes, I did include the billing information. And again, the browser-based translation works fine with my API key. The issue is the functioning of the R package.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the issue was related to the system. It works after I changed the https proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I also had some Problems with this and wrote a little function to retrieve the data from the API:

```
#' Translate with R
#'
#' Translate Keywords or/and text with the Google Translate API
#' The Functions allows to translate keywords or sentences using the Google Translate API.
#' To use this function you need to get a API-Key for the Google Translate API <https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/?hl=en>.
#' @param text The keyword/sentence/text you want to translate
#' @param API_Key Your API Key. You get the API Key here: <https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/?hl=en>
#' @param target The Language target your text translated to. For German 'de'. 
#' @param source The Language your given text/keyword is. For example 'en' - english 
#' translate()
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#' translate(text = "R is cool", API_Key = "XXXXXXXXXXX", target = "de", source = "en")
#' }


translate <- function(text,
                      API_Key,
                      target = "de",
                      source = "en") {
  b <- paste0(
    '{
    "q": [
    "',
    text,
    '"
    ],
    "target": "',
    target,
    '",
    "source": "',
    source,
    '",
    "format": "text"
}'
)
  url <-
    paste0("https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=",
           API_Key)
  x <- httr::POST(url, body = b)
  x <- jsonlite::fromJSON(rawToChar(x$content))
  x <- x$data$translations
  return(x$translatedText[1])
  }
```

Updated Gist here: https://gist.github.com/dschmeh/8414b63c3ab816c44995cd6872165f0e