# Using Google translate API and translateR, Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, api, google-translate, translate

I am trying to translate "alltexts" which is a character vector with 43 strings (texts) by using Google translate API and the package translateR (I have a valid API key). It works for a small sample of texts but the loop is not working, any ideas? Thanks in advance. Here is the code:

## translate alltexts with loop

```
for(i in 1:length(alltexts)){
translations <- translate(content.vec = alltexts, 
google.api.key = my.api.key, 
source.lang = 'fr', target.lang = 'en')
}
translations
```

## Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

Comment: A reproducible example would help. Maybe you need `alltexts[i]`...

Comment: That is difficult because the API key is not for free (unfortunately)...

Comment: @Christoph: no difference with alltexts[i]

Comment: What about [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48397295/5784831)? Perhaps `dput(alltexts)`.

Comment: @Christoph: Neither of these two options work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying alternative approaches, I assume the error pops up due to the automatically set google translation API limits, further info and how to change this see here:  http://code.markedmondson.me/googleLanguageR/articles/translation.html

Also, this approach of using google translate API seems more straight-forward: https://github.com/ropensci/googleLanguageR